# Autocomplete lookup field in Salesforce

Tags: autocomplete, salesforce

I would like to auto complete a lookup field in Salesforce.

My case:

If I add a new opportunity, I need to fill in an Account Name. I've added a consultant field that need to be filled in automatically by looking up the default consultant out of the account that I'd filled in at "Account Name".

So: Fill in Account Name -> Automatically check default consultant of the Account -> Fill in name at "Consultant".

Is that possible, if yes, how can I do it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want to use lookup filter rather than lookup autocomplete. In either of the case, you will still need to manually enter the value. Only thing is you can filter the value that you want as you type in or click the lookup icon.

For lookup auto complete got to Setup --> search settings --> lookup auto complete --> select the objects you want lookup autocomplete to be enabled.

for lookup filters --> go to the lookup field whch you want to filter --> add the filter based on other lookup field.